# Where is the hadoop task's hprof data stored when using oozie workflow - measuring memory usage

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hprof

I've followed the instructions in the hadoop definitive guide (also mentioned here [How to check memory footprint of Map Task in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314762/how-to-check-memory-footprint-of-map-task-in-hadoop)).  However, after the task is finished, I can't find any data to look at.

In the book it says that the data is moved to where the client is ran from...I'm using oozie workflow, I wonder where is the hprof data moved to in my case?

Comment: It depends on your Hadoop and/or Oozie version.

Comment: I'm seeing it appended to the job-tracker log...which gets annoying when saving hprof as binary format...any recomendations?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are places in the same place as all the other logs.  On cloudera dist, I found them on the data node: hadoop.job.history.location